# Uploading to a Teensy 4.0 via SparkFun FTDI Basic Breakout

Tags: ftdi, teensy

I have a large project which is being controlled by a Teensy 4.0 and I accidentally broke off the mini-USB. I will probably buy a new one anyway, but I wanted to try uploading using the RX TX pins to learn how to do it. I have a SparkFun FTDI Basic Breakout but all the tutorials I can find are for Teensy's, is there a tutorial which shows this, or can you tell me how to upload to a teensy from the Arduino IDE using FTDI? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload firmware to the Teensy 4.0 over a serial connection. Firmware upload is handled by an additional processor on the Teensy board which only communicates over USB and programs the main processor using its JTAG interface.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can upload a arduino using another arduino, you can search about it.

Comment: where is the answer